# Make <input /> appear on transitioning <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this setup:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  width: 800px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  justify-content: left;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.text-input {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .text-input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <div class=element>
      <input class=text-input type="text" name="search" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BOzJxL

I need the the textinput to appear next to the `hotpink div elemenet` (it needs to stay where it is when the `input` appears). I need it to appear bit-by-bit - sort of being revealed pixel by piyxel. When leaving the div, I want it to be hidden again - same style as it came in.

Comment: You are missing two closing `</div>` tags on your `element` div and your `wrapper` div.

Comment: @TimKlein Added the missing closing-tags.

Comment: `<div>` elements are not self-closing, so you cannot have this: `<div class=element/>`. It must have a closing tag to go along with it (`div`s are container elements which mean that you put other HTML elements inside them): `<div class=element></div>`.

Comment: @TimKlein edited that. Sorry. React-mode ;)

Comment: try to add margin: .text-input {
  display: none;
  margin-left:10px
}

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:30px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-input {
  max-width: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  -webkit-transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition:max-width 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover .text-input {
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <input class="text-input" type="text" name="search" />
</div>
```

Comment: the hotpink div disappears :-/